# How to append table inside textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ckeditor

How to add table inside textarea,

I am using ckeditor,

I  have tried like below

Rails code for teaxarea with cke editor

```
<%= text_area_tag :body,"<table id="table_id"></table>", :name => 'editor'%> 
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
</script>
```

Javascript code for appending a table inside teaxarea

```
success: function(data)
{
    var table = $('#table_id');
    table.find("thead tr").remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.temp_fields.length; i++) {
       table.append("<tr><th>"+data.temp_fields[i].field_name+"</th></tr>");
    }
}

But did not displayed any result inside textarea.
```

Comment: As answer of you question is no then please tell me more briefly why you want to append table in textarea so I will suggest another approach.

Comment: Possible dubplicate of `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911558/css-styling-for-table-inside-textarea`

Comment: Hi @ibnelaiq thanks for replying,  I want to send tracker to clients with table format, the tracker data is stored in db, i jsut need get that tracker data and display in table format inside ckeditor.so I can take  ckeditor data and send it.

Comment: Please tell me that can you replace a textarea with div? or can you add ckeditor table plugin.

Comment: hi @ibnelaiq, thanks for your reply, I have found different way, i,e rails way.So it is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `TEXTAREA` doesn't support `TABLE` to append in it as well as also several DOM elements are also not able to be appended.